# knockout js pass view param

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js, asp.net-core

I have a parameter in my mvc view as

```
@{
   var myparam = false;
}
```

I have my button in the same view as:

```
 <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Click" class="btn btn-primary" 
  data-bind='enable: selectvalue() != ""' />
```

in the data-bind of my button I also want to check for myparam. Something like below:

```
data-bind='enable: filterCategory() != "" && !myparam'
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Updated as below:

If my param is like below:

```
@{
  var myparam = false;
}
```

And my JS:

```
<script>
    var myData= @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
    myData.myParameter= "@myparam ";
</script>
```

My Knockout:

```
  (function () {
    var viewModel = function (data) {
         var viemod= this;
         viemod.myParam= vmData.myParam
 }
}
```

If I use this myData in my knockout js  as above it returns me "False" (string)
whereas it should be false (boolean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work because Razor runs server side. `myparam` is a `C#` local variable. So, you can't use it with knockout bindings which run client-side.

You can either create a  javascript variable and assign the value like this:

```
<script>
    var myparam = @Json.Encode(myparam);
</script>
```

or

If you don't want to pollute the global scope, add a `myparam` property to your viewModel.

```
var yourViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.myparam = @Json.Encode(myparam);
    self.filterCategory = ko.observable('');
}
```

After update:

As mentioned before, it should be

```
myData.myparam = @Json.Encode(myparam);
```

But since you're going to `.Serialize()` the entire model, you can assign the `myparam` to a property in the controller itself.

Comment: @aman As I mentioned in the answer, it should be `myData.myParameter= @Json.Encode(myparam);` In .net `false.toString()` returns "False"